# Probability that coordinate of a dot within a square less than random parameter Z

Tags: probability, probability-theory, geometric-probability

From square with vertices (0;0), (0;1), (1;1), (1;0) random dot was taken. It has coordinates (a;b). a and b are inside interval [0;1]. For random parameter z that is between [0;1] find probability that P(min(a,b) < 2z).

When I solve this task, I think like this:

P(min(a;b)<2z) = P(a<2z) * P(b<2z). And both of these two probabilities are equally possible. So I draw a square
[image: plot]

And find the probability that a<2z and it is 3/4.
Symmetrically for b<2z it is 3/4.
So the total P(min(a,b) < 2z) = 3/4 * 3/4 = 9/16

But some of my friends distinguish two intervals
z=[0;0.5) => Pr(min(a,b) < 2z) = 4z^2
and
z=[0.5;1] => Pr(min(a,b) < 2z) = 1

Which solution is right?
Thanks.

Comment: If you had written carefully the independence required to state that P(min(a;b)<2z) = P(a<2z) * P(b<2z), you would have seen that this identity does not hold. The approach due to "some of your friends" and described at the end of your post is much more sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(min(a,b)<2z)\ne P(a<2z).P(b<2z)$